# Cambiar una tupla de datos int a str

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysqlconnector

estoy intentando enlazar un combobox de tkinter con una tupla de datos numéricos. El error es: **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ljust'**
Creo que se debe a que los datos son números, dejo el código aquí:

```
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
query2="SELECT distinct(Cedula_conductor) as Cedula FROM conductores"
        
cursor1.execute(query2)
        
result=cursor1.fetchall()
        
lista6=[r for r, in result]
        
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Creo que la solución es convertir los datos de la tupla en str pero no sé cómo hacelo, claquiera que pueda ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: En la comprension de lista, r es el numero que tratas de ingresar en el combobox. Y la funcion str convierte en cadena el objeto que le pases. Por lo tanto, la solucion es aplicar la funcion str a r.

Comment: Gracias Dante, siempre sales a rescatarme.

Comment: De nada jajajaja, sospecho que soy uno de los pocos aqui que sabe sobre tkinter y por lo tanto da mas atencion a estas preguntas.

Comment: Si, me dí cuenta tarde de que no es muy popular. Acepté un contrato de programación que no estaba capacitado para aceptar y bueno ahí vamos dándole. El único lenguaje que había usado en la uni era python, pero me dí cuenta tarde de que hubiera sido mejor visual basic.

Comment: visual basic mejor que python? Es broma? No te preocupes, has elegido bien (al menos si la otra opción era VB) :-)

Comment: @carlosarraez y ni tanto, porque ya no se mucho vb (sin updates desde 2004) para desarrollo de aplicaciones, windows claro, usan más .NET con C#

Comment: Bueno, apliqué la de Richard Branson y hasta el momento el cliente está feliz. Esperemos que no me encuentre con que tkinter no puede cumplir todas las necesidades del programa. Por ejemplo, tengo que convertir los datos de mysql a un pdf o documento cualquiera y no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Primero, me parece que tkinter es el mas popular (pero en mi opinion hay uno mejor). Segundo, te deseo suerte y que lo logres compa! Y tercero, temo decirte que Tkinter casi no tiene formas de escribir archivos (el unico que conozco es convertir un canvas en postscript) no tiene ni para escribir pdf, ni word ni para imprimir (aunque en mi opinion deberia)

Comment: @DanteS. ¿Por qué debería TkInter ser capaz de generar PDFs? Solo es una biblioteca para crear interfaces gráficas de usuario. Para crear PDFs tienes otras bibliotecas en Python y nada te impide incluirlas y llamarlas desde Tkinter.

Comment: Me refiero a la capacidad de enviar a imprimir. Que es muy comun en las interfaces graficas si no me equivoco.

Comment: Si, exactamente cómo lo dice Dante. Conocen alguna librería que sea compatible con tkinter? Me refiero a que sea capaz de crear archivos para imprimir.

Comment: Querés crear archivos para imprimir (como pdfs) o enviar datos a la impresora?

Comment: Prefiero que sea un pdf que luego se pueda guardar o imprimir si el usuario desea.

Comment: Creo que entonces te servira la libreria pdfkit. Ademas, yo me referia antes a poder enviar datos a la impresora directamente con que tkinter tenga esa funcionalidad. En fin, suerte nuevamente!

Comment: Hola Dante, disculpa que insista en esta pregunta pero no me expliqué bien. Necesito una extensión que me permita crear un template desde la aplicación (sencillo, nada muy complicado es para una planilla que se tiene que imprimir y firmar). Pero todos los tutoriales que encuentro, crean el template desde html u otra fuente. Conoces una librería que me permita crear el template desde la aplicación?

Comment: Primero, recién me entero de que me escribiste. Te recomiendo mencionarme la proxima asi no te quedas colgado esperandome. Segundo, me podrías explicar que es un template por favor?

Comment: @DanteS. Tranquilo Dante, Template es el formato de lo que va en la hoja. Los datos que se van a sacar de mysql son placas de vehículos, nombres e identificaciones de choferes, mercancía, etc. Lo que el programa tiene que hacer es crear una hoja parecida a una factura, con todos los datos y la fecha, espacios para dos firmas (La del operador del programa y la del chófer). Y esa "factura" se imprimen dos copias. el template es la estructura de esa factura. (Que va donde y en que orden) No sé si me estoy explicando bien.

Comment: Creo que lo logro entender. Si es una cadena a interpretar, no conozco nada. Si no, no te sirve una librería que cree pdfs? Si no otra alternativa es usar modulos que sirvan para dibujar en las paginas como [pyside2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/)

Comment: @DanteS. estoy aprendiendo a usar Reportlab para eso, creo que esa librería tiene las herramientas que me hacen falta.

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende bien cual es la variable que tenes que castear, el código es poco claro, pero la manera de transformar tu tuple de ints a un tuple de str es

```py
cast = lambda x: str(x)

new_tuple = tuple(map(cast, my_tuple))
```

o podes directamente sobreescribir la variable asignando

```py
my_tuple = tuple(map(cast, my_tuple))
```

Comment: Gracias, al final lo que hice fué poner [str(r) for r, in result]

Comment: En realidad no se necesita la `lambda` intermedia. Perfectamente puedes hacer `map(str, my_tuple)`